# Can't programmatically move label in viewDidLoad

Tags: objective-c, ios, viewdidload

I'm trying to move a uiLabel down a drop if it's an iPhone 5 (4" display). But it's not working when the code is in viewDidLoad. If I call the code from clicking a uiButton, it works. Here's the code:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {
    if(CGSizeEqualToSize([[UIScreen mainScreen] preferredMode].size,CGSizeMake(640, 1136))) {
        CGRect frame = [self.timeOnCurrentQuestion frame];
        frame.origin.y += 40;  // change the location
        [self.timeOnCurrentQuestion setFrame:frame];
        nslog(@"This DOES get logged");
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think the frames are set yet when viewDidLoad is called, try it in viewDidAppearAnimated:

Comment: Is it possible that the frame is actually being set, but you don't notice it?  Wrap your update in an animation block, and delay it's execution a bit, that should show you exavtly what's happening.  Just use a performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: to call the frame setting code in a different method to fix it.

Comment: @CodaFi Interesting. If i make the delay .1, it moves down, but then moves back up. If it make it like .6-.7, it appears and quickly moves down. So that must mean it was being called before frame was set

Comment: @JonahKatz, yep.  viewDidLoad and awakeFromNib are not meant for visible changes to the view to take effect, they are for setting things up before the render buffer draws to the screen.

Comment: @CodaFi So what do you recommend i do?

Comment: @CodaFi Can autolayout vertically center a uiLabel between two other ones?

Comment: I imagine it could very easily, but it all depends on what you plan to do with the labels themselves.  Animations and debugging constraints become exponentially more challenging with auto-layout.

Comment: I have not tested this, but I think that you should do layout operations (like this) in `layoutSubviews`....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jonah, have you tried your code in viewWillAppear method? Possibly, it'll sort-out your issue.

Comment: ok, let me try by a sample code and will update you accordingly.

Comment: I've tried below code in my viewDidLoad, and it's working fine.Please have a look at this code.     NSString *str1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue]];
    NSArray* testArr = [str1 componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    
    if([[testArr objectAtIndex:0] isEqual:@"5"])
    {
        CGRect frame = [testLbl frame];
        frame.origin.y += 40;//78
        [testLbl setFrame:frame];
    }
    
    NSLog(@"The y of My Test Label is:->%d",(int)testLbl.frame.origin.y);
Hope, it'll what you're looking for. :)

Comment: In any concern, please let me know... :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that are something you need to beware of.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

It is a method that when the controller juz created its view.

for example: 
maybe in your init method, you call something like:

```
[self.view setBackground:[UIColor redColor]];
self.timeOnCurrentQuestion = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:kFrame];
```

In this case the work flow will be like this:

```
[self.view setBackground:[UIColor redColor]];
[self viewDidload];
self.timeOnCurrentQuestion = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:kFrame];
```

Th reason for this work flow is because the self.view is called, then its view is needed before the normal view cycle, so , in this case, self.timeOnCurrentQuestion is still nil in the viewDidload method.

I don't know if my practice is the best or not.

I always init the subView in the controller's init method.
and do the [self.view addSubview:_subview] (//or everything method call that require the self.view) in [self viewDidload];

Answer (score 0):

viewDidAppear worked for me.  The life cycle seems to be

1. LoadView()
2. viewDidLoad()
3. viewWillAppear()
4. viewDidAppear()